# What decides where TTY and boot messages are displayed?

Tags: fedora, arch-linux, tty, monitors, multi-monitor

I recently switched from Fedora 21 to Arch Linux, and one thing that bothers me is that Arch does not put boot messages and TTYs' on all available outputs like Fedora does, but only on the primary output regarding to the graphics card (the same monitor used for BIOS).

What decides what output is used to show these kind of "pre-display server"-things, and can I change it?

[image: TTY on Fedora 21, showing on both monitors]

Comment: This can be related to your bootloader, your graphics card, configured `getty`s and many other things. You can rest assured, though, that all messages are going to the TTY you configured - the arch linux folks rarely do more than minimum where config is concerned and leave it to you. Look at the default system.d `getty` service in `/etc/systemd/system` and `grub`'s *(if you're unlucky enough to be using it)* framebuffer configs and [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Working_with_the_serial_console) or [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netconsole).

Comment: It's not related to `getty` in this particular case. In the questioner's photograph of xyr old system, we can see a single virtual terminal (`tty2`) appearing on two monitors simultaneously.

Comment: I just realised that Arch does this as well when live booted. Extraordinary that it's available in live boot but not regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>It seems like nvidia-349.16-1 is broken. When I remove that package tty's show up on both monitors again.</del>

The nvidia driver (as opposed to the open source Nouveau driver) does not make use of the built in kernel mode setting in Linux which would support native resolution in the framebuffer (with TTY in correct resolution and also on all detected screens). Instead Nvidia makes use of a proprietary kernel mode setting.

I kind of stand by my initial conclution - it's broken. But by design it seems.

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_mode_setting

Comment: This, if I remember correctly, is fixed as of lately.